# egrep rest of line alpha

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, matching

I'm using grep to find verify some initial conditions at the beginning of a line, but I need the rest of the line after that to be alpha.  I can't figure out how to do it.

This is what I have so far:
^[0-9][0-9][0-9][[:alpha:]]+

This doesn't work because if there is say a number or space one or more characters after it still returns it.  I need it so just lines like 111saasniIUSABIBAFAib  get returned.

Thanks

-Mitchell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$` token to match the end of the line like so:

```
^[0-9][0-9][0-9][[:alpha:]]+$
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt and correct response.  I'll mark it correct as soon as I can. :)